# Dart Version Different in Pub Runner Than `flutter --version`

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, sdk, version

Here are the results of the `flutter --version` command:

```
Flutter 2.0.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 4d7946a68d (2 days ago) • 2021-03-18 17:24:33 -0700
Engine • revision 3459eb2436
Tools • Dart 2.12.2
```

Whenever I try to save my pubspec.yaml, I get this output:

```
The current Dart SDK version is 2.10.3.
...
Because adaptive_theme 2.0.0 requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.0 and no versions of adaptive_theme match >2.0.0 <3.0.0, adaptive_theme ^2.0.0 is forbidden.
```

I have this exact project on another computer with the same `pubspec.yaml`, same `pubspec.lock`, same flutter version. Everything is the same, but this one doesn't work.

EDIT:
Here is my environment from `pubspec.yaml`:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is that computer has Dart SDK installed with different version of Dart SDK embedded in Flutter.

Comment: How would I change the embedded version?

Comment: you do not need to change the embedded dart version It is better to remove the other dart sdk from the computer.

Comment: Okay, but how do I update the embedded version? It's too low of a version

Comment: No your embedded version 2.12.2 which is not low the other version is 2.10.3 which need to be updated, follow the link to see how to update it: [dart.dev](https://dart.dev/get-dart#install)